# Average of past five observations of same weekday

Tags: r

I have a data set with daily demand values. The dataset includes a column for the date, the demand and the weekday. I want a function to create a new column with the average demand for the past 5 observations of the same weekday. For example, for Monday Feb. 12th I would like a value of the average demand for the previous five Mondays. (Feb 5, Jan 29, Jan 22, Jan 15 and Jan 8).

Any ideas how I can code this in R?

Comment: You need to provide a data set where we can make some tests.

Comment: to elaborate on @OrhanYazar's point above; It's more likely that you will get a good answer if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `round_date` from the `lubridate` package and get means for dates over 7 days with the `by` argument in `data.table`:

Since there was no data, I created some random data:

**DATA**

```
dt <- data.table(var1 = runif(200, 0, 100), 
                 tme = seq.POSIXt(Sys.time(), by = "3 hour", length.out = 200))

> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  200 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ var1: num  82.3 62.7 79.3 48.4 92.9 ...
 $ tme : POSIXct, format: "2018-02-13 12:15:05" "2018-02-13 15:15:05" "2018-02-13 18:15:05" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

> head(dt)
       var1                 tme
1: 82.27774 2018-02-13 12:15:05
2: 62.72476 2018-02-13 15:15:05
3: 79.25656 2018-02-13 18:15:05
4: 48.44758 2018-02-13 21:15:05
5: 92.86983 2018-02-14 00:15:05
6: 82.83628 2018-02-14 03:15:05
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> dt[, list(mean_val = mean(var1)), by = list(period = round_date(tme, "7 days"))]
       period mean_val
1: 2018-02-15 47.77198
2: 2018-02-22 49.33726
3: 2018-03-01 41.00858
4: 2018-03-08 51.81597
```

Getting to begin on a certain date is not very difficult. There are options in `lubridate` to help you with that (e.g. [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/count-the-mondays-in-a-time-interval-with-lubridate/)). I could post the exact code but SO is not meant for that.